# Parsing a dataset of time in the format "Y-M-D H:M:S.MS" gives me 0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaN.NaNZ

Tags: d3.js, time, data-visualization, nan

I am able to see glucose readings but time shows up as: 0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaN.NaNZ
I am trying to parse a dataset of time of the format "Y-M-D H:M:S.MS". I need it to be formatted properly so that I can show it on the x axis. I have attached sample dataset to this code.
My code looks like this:

```
<script>
 function overview(){
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// // Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.utcFormat("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
      .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H"));

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft();

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.glucoseReading); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("glucose.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.time = parseDate(d.time);
        d.glucoseReading = +d.glucoseReading;
        console.log(d.time);
        console.log(d.glucoseReading);
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.glucoseReading; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the scatterplot
    svg.selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.time); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.glucoseReading); });

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

      });
}
overview();
</script>
```

My Dataset looks like:

[image: Dataset]

Answer (score 3):

You want to convert (parse) strings to dates, not the other way around. Therefore, instead of `d3.utcFormat()`, you have to use `d3.utcParse()`. On top of that, your specifier is incorrect: there is no timezone in your strings.

So, this should be your `parseDate` function and specifier:

```
var parseDate = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")
```

Here is it working (check your browse console, not the snippet's one):

```js
var parseDate = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")
var string = "2017-08-23 00:03:52.591";

console.log(parseDate(string))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```